Calculate height of a dynamic view using GeometryReader at SwiftUi
In my code I need "height" var to be refreshed depending of the size of the view (carousel). I thought that it could be possible by using GeometryReader, but the size is not correct :((
@SwiftUI.State var height: CGFloat = .zero

(...)

@ViewBuilder
func carousel(_ renderModel: renderModel) -> some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            AnotherView(
                (...)
            )
            }
        }
        .padding(.top, 20)
        .padding(.bottom, 10)
        .background(GeometryReader { geometry in
            Color.clear.onAppear {
                height = geometry.size.height
            }
        })
    }
    .frame(height: height)
}


Your code works for me: try replacing the content of the VStack with Text("height=\(height)") to see it working. You could simplify the example by removing the outer GeometryReader, which is not serving any purpose.

SwiftUI.Layout is a much better solution

@Benzy Neez
first GeometryReader is needed to calculate another size inside VStack so I can't delete it. The solution can't be correct because if I replace Color.clear with another color, the background covers more space than the view's size. It's as if the view is cropped, but the background still expands behind the cropped view.

@lorem ipsum which solution is it?

SwiftUI.Layout here  and here geometry ready has very limited appropriate use cases since this was released.

I'm not allowed to use Layout, my ios version is older. and I can't update it
